# Error Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, hilos

Después de que `Android-Studio` me advirtiera que hay demasiada carga al hilo principal.

> Skipped 113 frames: the application may be doing too much work on its main thread

He creado un runnable para lanzar un hilo con algunos procesos:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       UpdateUI(); //Actualiza datos de la Interfaz de usuario
    }
}
```

Pero me devuelve el error:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

He buscado por SO y se puede lanzar un hilo

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //Cambiar controles
    }
});
```

Pero como debo hacer muchas comprobaciones o bien se ejecuta un hilo al mismo tiempo, me devuelve lo de sobrecarga de main thread. Hasta noto que el menú lateral ralentiza al cerrarse.

¿Cómo se hace un hilo pero que pueda acceder a los elementos de la interfaz para poder modificar sus datos o estados?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para solucionar el error:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Se puede recurrir a `runOnUIThread` o bien `AsyncTask` dependiendo de la tarea a realizar, si requiere mucho proceso directamente a `AsyncTask`

**runOnUiThread** para ejecutar un hilo con acceso a los elementos dela interfaz:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //Cambiar controles
    }
});
```

**AsyncTask**

Para ejecutar una tarea que consume mucho, y mantener el usuario informado del proceso y al finalizar refrescar la UI:

- En `doInBackground` la tarea

Las siguientes permirten interectuar con los elementos de la UI

- En `onProgressUpdate` para informar de su transcurro
- En `onPostExecute` al finalizar refrescar la UI.

Ejemplo de un AsyncTask:

```
private class myUpdateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Intent, Integer, Boolean> {

        private Context mContext;
        private String title;

        public myUpdateAsyncTask (Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
        }


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Intent... intents) {
            //@Todo Tarea a procesar
            title = "soy un titulo asyncTask"
            publishProgress(1); //Para mandar control para actualizar la UI
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            //@Todo values[0] para obtener el código de control, actualizar la UI
            if (values[0]==1) textView.setText(title)
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result) {
                //@Todo AsyncTask finalizado
            }
        }

    }
```

#### Algunos Consejos

- Mirar de crear variables de control, si más de un proceso necesita obtener valor de una misma función.
- Solo actualizar los elementos de la interfaz que lo requieren, usando variables de control numéricas se puede predeterminar cuales afectan.

Comment: Que parametros se le debera asignar a getActivity()  ?

Comment: Si lo llamas desde la actividad prueba con (MainActivity.this)

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar y lo resolví de la siguiente manera en este ejemplo en el código del manejador del evento:

```
    private void Ws_OnOpened()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
            () =>
            {
                ws.Send(@"{""protocol"":""json"",""version"":1}" + recordSeparator);
                lblStatus.Text = "WS abierto";
                ws.Send("{\"arguments\":[\"" + "444" + "-1\"],\"invocationId\":\"" + "0" + "\",\"target\":\"JoinGroup\",\"type\":1}" + recordSeparator);
            }
            );
    }
```