# Error en RequestFocus: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, hilos

Porque me sale error cuando doy `RequesFocus` a mi campo de texto?

```
 public void Set_Conect(String Conect){
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr "+Frg_Logeo.get_usuario ());
            Frg_Logeo.get_conect ().setText ( Conect );
            Usuario.requestFocus ();
        }
```

En mi error me muestra:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

Ese error me sale por el focus? o hay algo malo que estoy haciendo?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68882/error-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(para especificar y ayudar a los que tienen problemas parecidos) lo utilice dentro de mi `Thread` y en el lugar que quiero que salga el `RequestFocus`: 
(dentro de tu hilo - `activity main`)

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
 frg_logeo.Set_Conect ( "Conectar" );
}
});
```

Y lo llamas desde tu clase que lo quieres usar:

```
public void Set_Conect(String Conect){
            Conec.setText ( Conect );
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr ");
            Usuario.requestFocus ( );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo para reforzar la respuesta, si usted utiliza un `Fragment` y tiene el mismo problema, también le puede servir:

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
         @Override
        public void run() {
             //colocar código acá
        }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]